# How to store meta data with Kafka topics (MSK)?

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

We're using Kafka/AWS MSK and we provision topics with Terraform. We have the need to store some meta data per topic, for example which `team`, `application` or `service` is responsible for a topic.

How can we store these types of meta data on Kafka topics?

Comment: Linkedin created datahub project for this purpose